# How to read in CSV columns in any order using CSVParser from apache.commons

Tags: java, csv, parsing, apache-commons

I have a csv file with some data in this format:

```
id,first,last,city
1,john,doe,austin
2,jane,mary,seattle
```

As of now I'm reading in the csv using this code:

```
    String path = "./data/data.csv";
    Map<Integer, User> map = new HashMap<>();

    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));

    try (CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {

        List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();

        for(int i=0; i < csvRecords.size(); i++){

            if(0<i){//skip over header
                CSVRecord csvRecord = csvRecords.get(i);
                User currentUser = new User(
                        Double.valueOf(csvRecord.get(0)).intValue(),
                        Double.valueOf(csvRecord.get(1)),
                        Double.valueOf(csvRecord.get(2)),
                        Double.valueOf(csvRecord.get(3))
                );
                map.put(currentUser.getId(), currentUser);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

which grab the correct values, but if the values were in a different order, say [city,last,id,first], it would be read incorrectly since the reading is hard coded with the order [id,first,last,city]. (the User object also must be created with the fields in the exact order of id,first,last,city)

I know that I can use the 'withHeader' option, but that also requires me to define the header column order in advance like so:

```
String header = "id,first,last,city";
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(header.split(",")));
```

I also know there is a [built in function getHeaderNames()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) but that only gets the headers after I've already passed them in as a string (so hard coding again). So if I passed in the header string "last,first,id,city" it would return exactly that in a list.

Is there a way to combine these bits to read in the csv no matter what the column orders are and to define my 'User' object with fields passed in order (id,first,last,city)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to tell the parser to process the header line for us. We specify that as part of the [`CSVFormat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html), so we'll create a custom format like this:

```java
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader();
```

Question code used [`DEFAULT`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#DEFAULT), but this is based on [`RFC4180`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#RFC4180) instead. Comparing them side-by-side:

```
DEFAULT                               RFC4180                       Comment
===================================   ===========================   ========================
withDelimiter(',')                    withDelimiter(',')            Same
withQuote('"')                        withQuote('"')                Same
withRecordSeparator("\r\n")           withRecordSeparator("\r\n")   Same
withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)            withIgnoreEmptyLines(false)   Don't ignore blank lines
withAllowDuplicateHeaderNames(true)   -                             Don't allow duplicates
===================================   ===========================   ========================
                                      withFirstRecordAsHeader()     We need this
```

With that change, we can call [`get(String name)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html#get-java.lang.String-) instead of [`get(int i)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html#get-int-):

```java
User currentUser = new User(
        Integer.parseInt(csvRecord.get("id")),
        csvRecord.get("first"),
        csvRecord.get("last"),
        csvRecord.get("city")
);
```

Note that [`CSVParser`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) implements `Iterable<CSVRecord>`, so we can use a for-each loop, which makes the code look like this:

```java
String path = "./data/data.csv";

Map<Integer, User> map = new HashMap<>();
try (CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path)),
                                         CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader())) {
    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
        User currentUser = new User(
                Integer.parseInt(csvRecord.get("id")),
                csvRecord.get("first"),
                csvRecord.get("last"),
                csvRecord.get("city")
        );
        map.put(currentUser.getId(), currentUser);
    }
}
```

That code correctly parses the file, even if the column order changes, e.g. to:

```
last,first,id,city
doe,john,1,austin
mary,jane,2,seattle
```

Comment: thanks! can you explain why we need RCF4180 instead of DEFAULT? I tried with both formats using the code you posted and it seems to work using DEFEAULT as well unless I'm missing something else

Comment: @reeeeeeeeeeee Please read the answer again. I added the comparison of `DEFAULT` and `RCF4180` for a reason. I even added comments explaining the differences.

Comment: yes i did read but i also plugged in DEFAULT instead of RCF4180 and found that it does indeed work and has withFirstRecordAsHeader() available

Comment: @reeeeeeeeeeee Of course it works, since your data doesn't have blank lines or duplicate header names. You do understand what those mean, right? The question is, which format is better, just in case those condition do occur in the data. Making the code react appropriately when something unexpected occurs is called [**defensive programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), which is a good thing to incorporate into your code. Ignoring error handling will cause you a lot of trouble later on.

Comment: got it. btw printing DEFAULT.getAllowDuplicateHeaderNames() and same for RCF... both return true.